# How to add asp.net mvc style context menu item for asp.net web site?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, visual-studio, web

I have a very large asp.net web site and I integrated asp.net mvc 5 there successfully. But now I didn't find any way to add feature, like, Add View, Add Controller, Go to View, etc from context menu. I know this can be done by changing Project GUID in Web Application.

So, what is the way for doing it for web site?

Answer (score 0):

In Visual Studio : **View** > **Solution Explorer** > Click right button on mouse on your project.

If you want go to view, right click on return in ActionResult